# Is there a way to set Outlook 2016 / Office 365 to only send out away messages during certain times of the day

Tags: microsoft-office-365, outlook-2016

I have an office 365 account and I was trying to find a way to make it so I can send out replies only during certain hours of the day without always having to manually change it.

Working half days now and would like to let clients know who email me directly where to contact for support and more.